# Consumir API a BD

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl

me encuentro trabajando en mi proyecto de titulación y debo hacer un sistema que trabaje en base a una API. Esta API debo integrarla a una Base de Datos, o sea, debo extraer toda la informacion referente a la empresa para la que trabajo e integrarla a una bd local. He probado varias maneras de hacerlo, pero me encuentro con el problema de que el servidor detecta demasiadas peticiones simultaneas. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
function cambiarFormatoFecha($fechaI){
    $cont = 0;
    while(strtotime($sumarDias)<strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))){
        $sumarDias = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fechaI. ' + '.$cont.' days'));
        $desarmar  = explode("-",$sumarDias);
        $nuevaFecha = $desarmar[0].$desarmar[1].$desarmar[2];
        $ch = curl_init();
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.mercadopublico.cl/servicios/v1/publico/ordenesdecompra.json?fecha=".$nuevaFecha."&CodigoOrganismo=7106&ticket=DF140AC7-B227-44C7-95DD-FEA0AF61C542");

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $result = json_decode($data,true);
        echo $nuevaFecha."<br>";
        if(is_array($result['Listado']) || is_object($result['Listado'])){
            $h = 0;
            sleep(10);
            foreach ($result['Listado'] as $value) {
                $ch2 = curl_init();
                $mh2 = curl_multi_init();
                curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.mercadopublico.cl/servicios/v1/publico/ordenesdecompra.json?Codigo=".$value['Codigo']."&ticket=DF140AC7-B227-44C7-95DD-FEA0AF61C542");
                curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
                curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
                curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                $data2 = curl_exec($ch2);
                curl_close($ch2);
                $result2  =json_decode($data2,true);
                if(is_array($result2['Listado']) || is_object($result2['Listado'])){
                    foreach ($result2['Listado'] as $value2) {
                        echo $value2['Codigo']." ".$value2['Nombre']." ".$value2['CodigoLicitacion']." ".$value2['TipoMoneda']."<br>";
                        sleep(10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //sleep(10);
        $cont++;
    }   
}
cambiarFormatoFecha('01-10-2018');
?>
```

Alguna idea/recomendacion para hacer esto? Es primera vez que trabajo con una API, y en un proyecto tan grande.

Comment: Estás lanzando peticiones a mansalva dentro de dos bucles.  ¿Por qué?  Deberías quizá reorganizar tu código. Aquí poco se te puede ayudar si no explicas lo que intentas hacer ahí, cuando lanzas dos `cURL`, uno dentro de un `while` y otro dentro de un `for`.

Comment: Si la verdad es que no me di el tiempo de explicar bien jeje. Necesito sacar detalles de ordenes de compra, estas OC tienen un codigo. El primer bucle es para obtener los codigos de ordenes de compra de un dia X, y el segundo es para obtener los detalles de todas esas OC. Tengo que almacenar toda esa informacion en una base de datos.

Comment: Y lo primero que hago es cambiar el formato de la fecha, ya que los codigos los obtengo ingresando una fecha en formato DDMMYYYY

Comment: Pero unas preguntas: Primero: ¿esa API está bajo tu dominio o es una API externa que la ha programado otro? Es lo primero que debes decir, porque si está bajo tu dominio lo correcto sería programarla para que en una sola petición te traiga los datos que requieres. Segundo: si es una API externa, ¿no hay una forma de consultarla que sea más sencilla, dándote exactamente los datos que quieres? Tercero, dices que el servidor se queja de demasiadas peticiones simultáneas, ¿qué servidor, el tuyo o el de la API?

Comment: Es una api externa que almacena datos de compras que las empresas realizan a proveedores del estado. Por ahora solo puedo acceder a la informacion obteniendo el codigo por fecha, y la OC por codigo, si quisiera graficar datos entre una fecha y otra necesito si o si tener todas esas OC, ya que la api no me permite extraer en base a un rango, ademas me pidieron como requerimiento que migrara toda la data a la BD. Y es el servidor de la api quien me limita las request.